# 504 nginx timeout after long periods of inactivity

Tags: nginx

when I haven't visited my page hosted in Nginx for more than a day. All request is failing with `504 gateway timeout`. I don't have any special configuration in my Nginx conf file. Just with default configuration pointing to my local file path.

Only after restarting the server I can get rid of the problem. what could be the possible issue?

Any ideas.

Comment: Post your nginx logs. Also run `nginx -T` and post the complete output in your question

Comment: Okay will do that